# Different inputs with the shared name in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

The screenshot below contains the **List** of items and the **Page** for the selected item.

When I click on any item from the **List**, the **Page** gets updated.

The object consists of id, fullName, username.

Inside **Page** there is a text input with name "username" for all of the items. The problem is that the text input doesn't change when I select a different item. I want to have different text inputs for different items. How do we handle it in React Hook Form?

[image]

Link to the project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-smoke-7zgew

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: @Bill, I have added the link to the project. Please, take a look!

Comment: i think the moment you click on the list, you need to use setValue to update the input. https://react-hook-form.com/api#setValue

Comment: @Bill, it worked. I have added useEffect to trigger the id change. Is it performance friendly solution?

Comment: yes. it shouldn't trigger re-render, if your input is registered via ref.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to **Page** solved the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue("username", profile.username);
}, [id]);
```